# get url or html tag from another origin's iframe on my html page. and prevent redirect to another origin,when click inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, iframe

I want to get an url from html iframe, before redirecting. I am using `https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/embed/zoom:9/centery:37.4460/centerx:24.9467/maptype:1/shownames:false/mmsi:232016954/shipid:0/fleet:/fleet_id:/vtypes:/showmenu:/remember:false` in my html page as a iframe.

```
  <iframe
  width="100%"
  height="450"
  src="https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/embed/zoom:9/centery:37.4460/centerx:24.9467/maptype:1/shownames:false/mmsi:232016954/shipid:0/fleet:/fleet_id:/vtypes:/showmenu:/remember:false"
  id="iframe"
></iframe>
```

Now when you will visit given url, you will find `vessel Details` button. Now whenever user click this url inside iframe on my html page, I want to retrieve Location of `vessel Details`'s url, before top level redirecting, even i don't want to redirect as well. when user click on `vessel Details` i want link location and redirect some where else on my server.

Comment: i think you cannot excess document from another origin  in you html?